# Can you both pattern-match on, and simultaneously unwrap a tuple containing optionals?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, pattern-matching, tuples, option-type

Trying to do something like this...

```
func test(a:Int?, b:Int?){

    switch (a, b) {

        case     (nil, nil) : print("Neither")
        case let (aa,  nil) : print("A-only: \(aa)")
        case let (nil, bb ) : print("B-only: \(bb)")
        case let (aa,  bb ) : print("A and B: \(aa) & \(bb)")
    }
}
```

where in the above, both `aa` and `bb` are already unwrapped.

Closest I could come up with is this...

```
func test(a:Int?, b:Int?){

    switch (a, b) {

        case (nil, nil) : print("Neither")
        case (  _, nil) : print("A-only: \(a!)")
        case (nil,   _) : print("B-only: \(b!)")
        default         : print("A and B: \(a!) & \(b!)")
    }
}
```

...but I really hate that I have explicitly unwrapped values like that.

So can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the “optional pattern” `x?`:

```
func test(a:Int?, b:Int?) {

    switch (a, b) {

    case (nil, nil) : print("Neither")
    case (let aa?,  nil) : print("A-only: \(aa)")
    case (nil, let bb?) : print("B-only: \(bb)")
    case (let aa?, let bb?) : print("A and B: \(aa) & \(bb)")
    }
}
```

`x?` is a shortcut for `.some(x)`, so you can equivalently write this
as

```
func test(a:Int?, b:Int?) {

    switch (a, b) {

    case (nil, nil) : print("Neither")
    case (let .some(aa), nil) : print("A-only: \(aa)")
    case (nil, let .some(bb)) : print("B-only: \(bb)")
    case (let .some(aa), let .some(bb)) : print("A and B: \(aa) & \(bb)")
    }
}
```

As @vacawama said, you can also move the `let` to the outside of the pattern:

```
    case let (aa?,  nil) : print("A-only: \(aa)")
    case let (nil, bb?) : print("B-only: \(bb)")
    case let (aa?, bb?) : print("A and B: \(aa) & \(bb)")
```

Comment: Or `case let (aa?, bb?)` for the last one.

Comment: `let (aa?,  nil)` works also for the other cases. Or `let (.some(a),  nil)`